# Lightbox not loading dynamic selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, lightbox

Could really do with some assistance with this:

So I am using a lightbox called featherlight. I have a form in there, the form has a few input fields but the two I need help with are a country selection, so you select either Us or UK and whichever one you select the next options list change accordingly.

Now, It works perfectly fine outside the lightbox so directly onto the body, yet as soon as I place it in the form within the lightbox it fails.

Here is my script for the dynamic selectors.

```
<script>

var ukCities = ['Avon', 'Bedfordshire', 'Berkshire'];
var usCities = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

$(document).on("change", "select.country", function() {
    var country = $("select.country").val();
    var cities;
    if(country === 'UK'){
        cities = ukCities;
    }
    else{
        cities = usCities;
    }
    $("select.city").empty();
    $.each(cities, function(index, element){
            $("select.city").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country).text(element));
    });
});
$("select.country").val('UK').trigger('change');

</script>
```

Here is the form:

```
 <select style="width: 64%;" name="country" class="country">
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="US">US</option>
            </select>


            <select class='city'>

            </select>
```

Here is a demo of it in action:

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CKA4/1/)

so the primary issue is that it will not work in the lightbox, I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Is there anyone out there who can give me a pointer? I really need some help :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your javascript to a function, and bind it once you load your featherlight.

```
$(document)
```

This means that your script is being applied to DOM elements on page load. If featherlight is loading your select menus after the DOM is loaded, then you will need to bind your javascript code to the new elements manually.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you mean, do you have an example?

Comment: Does featherlight load the select menus after the page is loaded? Via ajax?